# DiagrammeR How can I left align text in nodes using HTML

Tags: r, diagrammer

How can I left-align text in DiagrammeR::graphviz() when I use HTML code?

I need to insert bullet points, venus and mars signs into the nodes, and I have only been able to do this using HTML.

I can find several posts describing how to left-align when not using HTML (\\l), but I can't find any posts on how to do it using HTML.

How can I left-align the text in the nodes when using HTML?

Reprex:

````
```{r}
DiagrammeR::grViz("
digraph rmarkdown{

# Box
node [shape = box
     fontname = Helvetica,
     penwidth = 1.0,
     fixedsize = true,
     width = 3,
     height = 1]

A;

A[label = 
<
Top row<br/> 
&#8226; Bullet one<br/> 
&#8226; Bullet two with more words<br/>
&#9792; A venus sign
>]
}
")
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer here: https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html

You need to insert the line ALIGN = 'LEFT' in the HTML line break code.

See below:

````
DiagrammeR::grViz("
digraph rmarkdown{

# Box
node [shape = box]

A;

A[label = 
    <
    Top row<br ALIGN = 'LEFT'/> 
    &#8226; Bullet one<br ALIGN = 'LEFT'/> 
    &#8226; Bullet two with more words<br ALIGN = 'LEFT'/>
    &#9792; A venus sign <br ALIGN = 'LEFT' />
    >
]

}
")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to left-align the text without adding white space (i.e., a blank line) at the bottom of the box?

Comment: I don't think that's possible because the `ALIGN` argument is embedded inside the linebreak (`<br>`). So the whitespace is there because of a line break.

Comment: Is there not another way to left align text than with using a linebreak?

Comment: I don't think there is.  I have checked the documentation and could not find anything.